# What was the first published book set during a Covid-19 lockdown?

Tags: history-of-literature

The onset of the Covid-19 pandemic changed the world and many people's lives in countries all over the world in 2020. Much [has been written](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2020/jun/01/no-pubs-no-kissing-no-flying-how-covid-19-is-forcing-authors-to-change-their-novels) about how writers of fiction have needed to change or shelve their manuscripts to reflect the new state of the world, or to avoid the temporal setting of their stories being [impossible to place](https://xkcd.com/2384/).

Since so many of these changes have happened so quickly, in the future it may be very hard to pin down a timeline or to figure out who was the first person to get a book published which was really set during the Covid-19 pandemic. I'm hoping that, by asking this question now in 2021 when it should be easier to answer, I'm creating something which will be of value to future historians of literature.

**What was the first-published fiction story, in any language, set during Covid-19 lockdown?**

Clarifications (more may be added if necessary):

- Any type of story counts, but it must be formally **published**, not just a blog post or the like which a good writer could do in a day. (For bonus points I'd also be interested in the first *novel*, or similarly lengthy piece of literature.)
- Any Earth setting is OK, even fictional countries, but there must be a **lockdown** which affects the lives of the characters. A casual mention of a news story about a virus in far-off China doesn't qualify.

Comment: By "story", are you including or excluding narrative poems?

Comment: @bobble Sure, anything fictional, but see my first bullet point.

Comment: Specifically during a Covid-19 lockdown or just during the current pandemic?

Comment: @Tsundoku There are varying degrees of "lockdown", but anything which is significantly affecting the workings of society or the lives of the characters.

Comment: It's not written as a novel, but the Japanese TV drama "Remolove", which aired on NTV October-December 2020 works the Covid pandemic into its story line very cleverly.

Answer (score 2):

[*Wuhan Diary: Dispatches from a Quarantined City*](https://www.harpercollins.com/products/wuhan-diary-fang-fangmichael-berry?variant=32205368295458) by Fang Fang (translated by Michael Berry was published in e-book format by HarperCollins in 15 May 2020. (The [hardcover edtion](https://www.harpercollins.com/products/wuhan-diary-fang-fangmichael-berry?variant=32291831185442) is dated 24 November 2020.) This is obviously set during a lockdown but is not fiction.

Several of the earliest novels that are explicitly set during a lockdown in Europe are self-published:

- [*COVID-19: UN ROMAN GLOBAL DANS UN MONDE GLOBAL*](https://www.amazon.fr/COVID-19-ROMAN-GLOBAL-DANS-MONDE/dp/B088B6WLMK/) by Dr. Joseph Adrien Emmanuel DEMES M.D. M.P.H. Ph.D. (obviously a very serious author): published on **30 April 2020**;
- [*UN AMOUR DE CONFINEMENT*](https://www.amazon.fr/AMOUR-CONFINEMENT-H%C3%A9l%C3%A8ne-TAVELLE/dp/B08BDRB37J/) by Hélène Tavelle: published on 17 June 2020 ("confinement" can mean quarantine or lockdown);
- [*Lockdown: Liebe in Zeiten von Corona*](https://www.amazon.de/Lockdown-Liebe-Zeiten-von-Corona/dp/B08KH3QMCP/) by Agnes Bonus is a short-story collection published on 29 September 2020;
- [*Futur proche*](https://www.amazon.fr/Futur-proche-Fran%C3%A7ois-Morin/dp/B08KGQTP4N/) by François Morin: published on 30 September 2020 (set in a country *after* the Covid-19 pandemic and where liberty has been seriously reduced and the health system has failed);
- [*Plandemic*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Plandemic-John-Reizer/dp/B08H6RVX3R/) by John Reizer was published on 1 September 2020; the summary on Amazon.co.uk does not explicitly mention a lockdown but says "While most people in the world remain paralyzed by fear"; the novel capitalises on conspiracy myths;

  - ([*Plandemic*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Plandemic-Matthew-Burlington/dp/B0892HQTLF/) by Matthew Burlington was published on 23 May 2020 but is about a "deadly plague epidemic", not Covid-19, and therefore does not count);
- [*Covid-19-Roman [10.10.20]*](https://www.amazon.de/Covid-19-Roman-10-10-20-Romanovelle-Sars-Al-Klausens/dp/375262678X/) published on 19.10.2020 under the pseudonym Sars Al-Klausen; the cover says "An einem Tag geschrieben", i.e. written on a single day.

Not self-published but not explicitly set during a lockdown:

- [***Corona***](https://keinundaber.ch/de/autoren-regal/martin-meyer/corona/1160) by the Swiss author Martin Meyer was published by Kein & Aber in May 2020 and reviewed in [*Der Tagesspiegel*](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/kultur/der-erste-corona-roman-martin-meyers-erzaehlung-corona/25913182.html) on 15 June 2020. The novel is about a bookseller who has symptoms of a Covid-19 infection and who therefore lives in quarantine. What I could find about this novel does not explicitly mention a lockdown.
- [***Das Corona-Ende***](https://steffen-verlag.de/buecher-trainingskarten/bestseller/923/das-corona-ende) by  Dorit Biel and Matti Sund, published by Steffen Verlag on [**12 May 2020** according to Amazon.de](https://www.amazon.de/Das-Corona-Ende-Roman-Matti-Sund/dp/3957990971/); this novel is about a woman who is involved in the development of Corona medication (not a vaccine) while her husband is infected and therefore urgently needs the medication; the authors wrote the book during a **self-imposed two-week quarantine**.
- [*Als mein Leben verrückt spielte und dann auch noch Corona kam*](https://www.debehr.de/buch.php?id=702) by Anke Ernst, published by DeBehr on [27 July according to Amazon.de](https://www.amazon.de/mein-Leben-verr%C3%BCckt-spielte-Corona/dp/395753786X/).
- [***Das Baby ist meins***](https://www.aufbau-verlag.de/index.php/das-baby-ist-meins.html) by Oyinkan Braithwaite, published by Aufbau-Verlag on [18 January 2021](https://www.amazon.de/Das-Baby-ist-meins-Roman/dp/3351050895) is described as the **"first real lockdown novel"** in the blogpost [Der erste echte Lockdown-Roman: “Das Baby ist meins” von Oyinkan Braithwaite](https://blog.wdr.de/nollerliest/der-erste-echte-lockdown-roman-das-baby-ist-meins-von-oyinkan-braithwaite/) on the blog of WDR ("West-German Broadcast") (3 February 2021). The justification for this description is that the lockdown is not simply used as in a diary but is used as a **major plot element** ("strukturell und dramaturgisch alles entscheidend").
  The English edition, *The Baby Is Mine*, by [Atlantic Books](https://atlantic-books.co.uk/book/the-baby-is-mine/) is scheduled for publication on 27 May 2021.

Answer (score 0):

The [Staying Home series](https://www.wheelers.co.nz/browse/series/743663-the-staying-home-series/) of picturebooks explaining the Covid-19 pandemic restrictions was published in New Zealand 21 May 2020, but may have been produced overseas earlier than this. Unfortunately I am unable to find any other information.